# How to display math solutions on a new activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am building an Android app. How can I get the calculations' solutions to be displayed on a new activity?

Comment: Step 1) Google. Step 2) Try.

Answer (score 0):

Make your calculation in Activity A.

And send them to the other activity using `intent.putExtra(...)`

Take a look in [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

On activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("YourKeyWord", yourVariableWithValue);
startAcvitity(intent);
```

On activity B

```
int result;
Bundle extras = getIntent.getExtras();
if (extras =! null) {
    result = extras.getInt("YourKeyWord");
}
```

Comment: Can u please make a little example say for a+b , with the answer appearing on a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Activity A:

```
public class First extends Activity{
int a,b,c;   
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    a = 1,b = 2;
    c = a + b;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
    intent.putExtra("result", c);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Activity B:

```
public class Second extends Activity{   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int result = intent.getExtras().getInt("result");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed . Thanks